# Looking for emoji library or SDK for android to use it in keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I am developing android keyboard, but I am not able to create multi page of emoji's, is there any "free" emoji library for android keyboard.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I couldn't find a way in this documentation to create emoji layout in my keyboard that contains all emojis ..